# Django RESTAPI how to make calculation APIs PUT or POST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm trying to make calculation rest api using django.

My objective is to save preprocessed_data(result) into the db table field

The process is read raw data path(txt file) from db and calculate using pandas & numpy
after that make result txt file save to db preprocessed_data field.

this is my models.py

```
class PreprocessData(models.Model):

    raw = models.FileField(
        upload_to=_user_directory_path,
        storage=OverwriteStorage(),

    preprocessed_data = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
)
```

and views.py

```
class PreprocessCalculate(APIView):
    def _get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            data = PreprocessData.objects.get(id=pk)
            return data
        except PreprocessData.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound

#get or put or post which is the best design for api?

# PUT API
    def put(self, request, pk):
        data = self._get_object(pk)
        serializer = PreprocessCalculateSerializer(data, request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            updated_serializer = serializer.save()
            return Response(PreprocessDataSerializer(updated_serializer).data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and serializers.py

```
class PreprocessResultField(serializers.CharField):
    def to_representation(self, value) -> str:
        ret = {"result": value.test_func()}
        return ret

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data["result"]


class PreprocessCalculateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    preprocessed_data = PreprocessResultField()

    class Meta:
        model = PreprocessData
        fields = ("uuid", "preprocessed_data")
```

my question is

1. when I use the above code. In db "preprocessed_field" is still null... what is the problem in custom field serializer?
2. I choose "PUT" method to calculate raw file, but I think if I use "PUT" it has a problem to change my "uuid" by mistake. I think it is not good .. then should I use GET or POST? to make calculation restAPI?
   If "PUT" is right how to keep idempotent my db?

Pleas help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality, you can use any method you want (although, there are some [principles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/630453/7100120) related to it). Another important thing is that you do need to know what kind of file you are going to process. Here is a simple example, that only accepts `.csv` files upload, read its data and do different processes depending on the kind of `request.method`:

models.py

```py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return "user_{0}/{1}".format(instance.user.id, filename)


class PreprocessData(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    raw = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py ([`extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) on serializer)

```py
class PreprocessCalculate(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PreprocessDataSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"method": request.method}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = PreprocessDataSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"method": request.method}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

processors.py

```py
def post_pre_process(file):
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    calculation = data.to_numpy().sum()
    return calculation

def put_pre_process(file):
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    calculation = data.to_numpy().prod()
    return calculation
```

serializers.py

```py
class PreprocessDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PreprocessData
        fields = ['user', 'raw', 'result']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'result': {'read_only': True}
        }
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        """Only .csv files are accepted"""
        filename, ext = attrs["raw"].name.split(".")
        if not ext == "csv":
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"msg": "File must be .csv"})

        return super().validate(attrs)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        method = self.context.get('method')
        if method == 'POST':
            validated_data['result'] = post_pre_process(validated_data['raw'])
        if method == 'PUT':
            validated_data['result'] = put_pre_process(validated_data['raw'])
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

About the other Questions:

> when I use the above code. In db "preprocessed_field" is still null...
> what is the problem in custom field serializer?

In your code you return a object not a `string` and there is also `value.test_func()` that is nowhere to be seen, if it would return a string then your `.to_representation` should return `ret['result']`.

> I choose "PUT" method to calculate raw file, but I think if I use
> "PUT" it has a problem to change my "uuid" by mistake. I think it is
> not good .. then should I use GET or POST? to make calculation
> restAPI? If "PUT" is right how to keep idempotent my db?

As I stated `POST` and `PUT` are okay. Also, `uuid` will not change if `editable=False`. Lastly, the result is always the same, for both kind of requests. For instance, suppose a `.csv` files contains.

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

then, `POST` will always return

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "raw": "/media/user_1/myfile_ciacf5j.csv",
    "result": "15"
}
```

in the same way `PUT`

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "raw": "/media/user_1/myfile_bljuHte.csv",
    "result": "120"
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your kind explanation. It is really helpful.